# Php excel in one cell

Tags: php, sql-server, excel, formatting, sqlsrv

I am working on creating excel from my SQL server, the problem is that the row is in one cell. I want the output to be on each cell in the same row. That will make it easier to edit and sum data.

This is the query and the output in the sql server:

[image]

Output in the Excel file:

[image]

Code:

```
$sql = "
SELECT measurements.title as Tittel, routines.value as Verdi, convert(VARCHAR(10), routines.time, 108) as Tid, pools.name as Basseng, emps.user_name as Ansatt
FROM routines, measure_routine, measurements, pools, emps
WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
AND (measurements.title  Like 'T_%') AND measure_routine.pool_id=pools.id AND routines.emp_id=emps.id 
AND pools.name = 'Hovedbasseng' 
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
";

 $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . sqlsrv_error(). "<br>" . sqlsrv_errno()); 

$file_ending = "xls";
$reals=array();
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/csv");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

$i=0;
foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $result ) as $fieldMetadata ) {    
       echo $fieldMetadata["Name"]+"\t";
       if($fieldMetadata["Type"]=="real")//$fieldMetadata["Type"]=== SQL_REAL
       {
           $reals[] = $i;
       }
       $i++;
}


print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
   $schema_insert = "";
   for($j = 0; $j < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $j++)
   {
      if ($row[$j] != "") {
         if (in_array($j, $reals)) {
            $schema_insert .= str_replace(".",",", $row[$j]) . $sep;
         } else {
            $schema_insert .= $row[$j] . $sep;
         }
      }
      else
         $schema_insert .= "" . $sep;
   }
   $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
   $schema_insert .= "\t";
   print(trim($schema_insert));
   print "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Learn to use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function; stop trying to use `,` as a decimal point in a CSV; validate output in a text editor first, not in MS Excel; and what are you trying to do with `$schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
`?

Comment: You're using TAB as separator in a COMMA-separated-values output...

Comment: Yes, in the text editor it showed as, I am unsure why it is showing 0's at first. How is the proper way to put the values in each cell ?`00000T_Badende_per_Time 60 10:29:41 Hovedbasseng BilAhm` @MarkBaker I dont know why that code is there, I removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams - tab is perfectly valid as a separator

Comment: @MarkBaker - I agree: *unless* you're trying to write a valid CSV output and have it open as expected in Excel without all the content on each row ending up in one cell, which is the exact problem the OP is having...

Comment: I have some insight into CSV and MS Excel files, and understand the problems: one of the problems with CSV and MS Excel is that the separator is locale specific, unless you explicitly write a `sep=<x>` record as the first row of the file

Comment: How do you think that can be done with `set=<x>` in my case?

Comment: Have you considered using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)? It's quite a bit more complex to write, but the results are much more reliable, in that you don't have to get your users to wade through the CSV import wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:
Open phpMyadmin
Log in
open table you want to grab
click export
choose file type you want to export it as